# How to use ext-debug.js with ExtJs 5.0?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

In ExtJs 4.2, I always used `ext-debug.js` in the development environment. The advantage over `ext-all-debug.js` is that each class gets loaded as a separate file, and as a consequence the backtrace in the developer tool is much clearer.

I made an upgrade from ExtJs 4.2 to 5.1, and my app.json looks like:

```
/**
 * Comma-separated string with the paths of directories or files to search. Any classes
 * declared in these locations will be available in your class "requires" or in calls
 * to "Ext.require". The "app.dir" variable below is expanded to the path where the
 * application resides (the same folder in which this file is located).
 */
"classpath": "${app.dir}/app",
/**
 * The Sencha Framework for this application: "ext" or "touch".
 */
"framework": "ext",
"js": [
    {
        "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true
    }
],
```

When I change the line to

```
"path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-debug.js"
```

- sencha build failes with this error

  ```
  [INF] Capturing theme image
  [ERR] loading page W%3A/mbgest25dev/sass/example/theme.html
  registering ready listener...
  [E] [Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.
  ... dozens of times the same error
  ```
- `ext-debug.js` gets loaded, but all the classes are loaded with a wrong URL (and get 404 errors)
  `GET http://example.com/packages/sencha-core/src/class/Mixin.js?_dc=1427986581354` instead of  `GET http://example.com/app-directory/ext/packages/sencha-core/src/class/Mixin.js?_dc=1427986581354`

Certainly, the errors in `sencha app build` are the same than in the browser.

There must be a missing configuration that tells `ext-debug.js` where to look for the framework, while `ext-all-rtl-debug.js` doesn't need to know.

How to configure ExtJs 5.0 to work with `ext-debug.js` to be able to benefit from the clearer and more relevant stack trace ?

Edit:

Adding the path to the ext framework classes to the `classpath` like `"classpath": "${app.dir}/app,${app.dir}/ext",` does not help. `sencha cmd` gives some warnings and finally fails to build the app.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove these lines

```
{
        "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
}
```

in app.json you will achieve what you want (Ext will load the required classes what is written in your bootstrap.json file).

Comment: Thank you very much. This was blocking for me for upgrading my app to ExtJs 5. Meanwhile ExtJs6.0 came out. I cannot check if your answer is correct for now, but certainly this allows me to try an upgrade to Ext 6.0 somewhen.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration can be handled in three places, usually in the following order:

- .sencha/sencha.cfg
- app.json
- app.js (or Application.js)

If you are upgrading from Ext JS 4, there is a good chance it's in sencha.cfg. Look for **app.framework** and **app.classpath**.

Next check app.json, and look for the same settings that could be overriding this. If all else fails, try forcing your paths by setting them against Ext.application in app.js using **paths** property (an object mapping namespace to directory structure).

Comment: The documentation included in app.json says that **framework** should be either `ext` or `sencha`. **classpath** on the other hand tells where the loader should look for the app's classes. It is `"classpath": "${app.dir}/app"` in my case. It would not make sense to me to add `${framework.dir}` or `${app.dir}/ext`, would it? I will give it a try, but I'm sceptical.

Comment: I tried what you recommended, but I was not able to get it to work. See edit. Maybe you can give some more specific advice ?

Comment: Can you show us the output of your bootstrap.json after the app is refreshed/compiled? Somewhere your base package directory is not getting set properly, it's hard to say without seeing some of your configuration files.

Comment: The problem is that bootstrap.json is about 76k. I also tried with an app generated with `sencha generate app`, and even with that, it is not possible to use `ext-debug.js`. The behavior is exactly the same. Im using ExtJs GPL 5.1.0.107 and Sencha Cmd 5.1.2.52. If even the clean standard app does not build with `ext-debug.js` it looks like a bug in ExtJs to me.

Comment: I looked closer into bootstrap.json, and it looks fine. The problem has its origin not in this file as far as I can understand. The first request going wrong is to `http://domain/packages/sencha-core/src/class/Mixin.js`, while bootstrap.json contains correctly: `"Ext.Mixin":"ext/packages/sencha-core/src/class/Mixin.js"`.